# Google Sign in not in UIVIewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, google-signin

I am trying to create a class which is going to handle all login services on my project. Everything is worked fine except Google Sign in.

I want implement Google Sign-in not in UIVIewController as mentioned on Google documentation you can do this by using `GIDSignInDelegate` and use it when your class is not an UIViewController.

My class is extended from `NSObject` and want Google SignIn handled on that service and after that I want just call one method to do this.

```
var ls: LoginService = LoginService.instance
 ls.doGoogleLogin()
```

Here is my LoginService:

```
struct LOGIN_URL {
    static let LOGIN: String = "login"
}

protocol LoginServiceDelegate: class {
    func loginSuccess(loginResponse: User)
    func loginFailed(message: String)
}

class LoginService: NSObject, GIDSignInDelegate{

    static let instance = LoginService()

    weak var delegate: LoginServiceDelegate?

    var user: User?

    func doGoogleLogin(){
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
//        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print(user.profile.email)
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

when I am using this code I got an error 
`value of type LoginService has no member presentViewController`

What should do here do not get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By typing `self.presentViewController`, you are saying that the class that `self` is referencing is an object type that can use the method `presentViewController`. In this case, when you say `self`, you are referencing a `LoginService` instance. `LoginService` inherits from `NSObject`, which means it is not an object- like a `View Controller` or `Navigation Controller` that can call that method.

I think you need to add delegate methods at the top of your LoginService class.

```
protocol LoginServiceDelegate: class {
  func loginSuccess(loginResponse: User)
  func loginFailed(message: String)
  func googleSignInLaunch(_ viewController: UIViewController)
  func googleSignInDismiss(_ viewController: UIViewController)
}
```

Then when you call:

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    //call delegate method here
    //which will trigger view controller calling this to launch something
    delegate?.googleSignInLaunch(_ viewController: UIViewController)
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
            dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    delegate?.googleSignInDismiss(_ viewController: UIViewController)
}
```

Then in the View Controller calling your login service:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

  let loginService = LoginService()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    loginService.delegate = self
    loginService.doGoogleLogin()
  }

  func googleSignInLaunch(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func googleSignInDismiss(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }

  //the methods below are the other two methods that were in your LoginService protocol

  func loginSuccess(loginResponse: User) {
    //whatever you need to do
  }

  func loginFailed(message: String) {
    //whatever you need to do
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoginService` class is not a `UIViewController` so running `presentViewController` will not work. Try getting the top-most ViewController with the following code and call `presentViewController` on that ViewController.

```
if var topController = UIApplication.shared().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
        topController = presentedViewController
    }

    // Call presentViewController on topController
}
```